# Check balance with AT command

Tags: c#, at-command

I am trying to check balance by sending

```
at+cusd=1,"*778#",15
```

But it returns

```
+CUSD: 0,"00420061006C0061006E00630065003A002000390034002E0039003200200054004B00
2E002000560061006C00690064006900740079003A002000300034002D004D00610079002D003100
34002E00200042006F006E00750073003A00200030002E003000300054004B002E00200046007200
6500650020004D0069006E003A00200030002E0046005200450045002000540075006E0065007300
210020004400690061006C002A003100320031002A00320031003100380033002300530065006900
2000540075006D0069002000620079004C00520042002E00440069006E006E006500720077006900
7400680020004D0069006D0020006400690061006C002A003800370037002A003100320031003900
310023",72
```

How to convert it in normal text?

Comment: Looks like hex.. and each other byte is nil, so its possibly unicode code points or UTF-8.  Convert it to a byte array and ask the UTF-8 encoder for a string back.

Comment: It's hex-encoded UTF-16. What language do you want to use to convert it?

Comment: Iain has a good sample there for you.

Comment: Message reads: "Balance: 94.92 TK. Validity: 04-May-14. Bonus: 0.00TK. Free Min: 0.FREE Tunes! Dial*121*21183#Sei Tumi byLRB.Dinnerwith Mim dial*877*12191#"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dan-o said:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray (this String HexString) {
    int NumberChars = HexString.Length;
    var bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2) {
      bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(HexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
  }
```

Then `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ToByteArray(myString));`

If that comes out jumbled, try `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(...)` instead.

Comment: Here is an error- 'System.Text.Encoding' does not contain a definition for 'UTF16'

Comment: Sorry, faulty coding from faulty memory. Now corrected.